# How to inspect the threading.local data of another thread by getting access to _local__impl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

For educational purposes only, I would like to access the thread local data in another thread.

Checking the [threading.local source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/_threading_local.py), I can see that the way thread local data is implemented is by creating a dictionary named `_local__impl` that maps thread ids to a dictionary of data. When any thread attempts to look up an attribute on the thread local object, `__getattribute__` is patched and temporarily replaces the thread local object's `__dict__` with the sub dictionary stored in `_local__impl` by looking it up with the thread's id.

What I basically want to do is get a handle on this `_local__impl`:

```
import threading

l = threading.local()

master_dict = l._local__impl

for thread_id, thread_local_data in master_dict.items():
    print(thread_id, thread_local_data)
```

However, calling `l._local__impl` is getting patched by the `_patch` method defined in the source code, which effectively prevents access to this object.

Comment: Have you tried using `object.__getattribute__(l, _local__impl)`, like the code there does? That is, using the `object` class's version of `__getattribute__()` to obtain the attribute of `l`, rather than `l`'s version

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Yes I tried this `object.__getattribute__(l, '_local__impl')` but it raises `AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute '_local__impl'` oddly enough.

Comment: Then are you sure you're looking at the right implementation? The source code you linked is not from `_thread` - I dunno where that particular source code is, but it's somewhere else.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy You're right - The `threading.py` [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/threading.py#L1314) first tries to import a C version of `_threading_local.py` and only if that fails will it import the python version. Here is the [C source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/762f93ff2efd6b7ef0177cad57939c0ab2002eac/Modules/_threadmodule.c#L557)